# Help rendering booktabs tables in RStudio

Tags: r, booktabs, rstudio

Can I use the booktabs package in R? I am using RStudio and could not find a way to install a version of the booktabs package.

The table I am trying to render in a .Rmd file is provided below:

```
%----- Requires booktabs package -----%
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \caption{Descriptive Statistics}
    \label{tab:descriptiveStatistics}
    {
        \begin{tabular}{lr}
            \toprule
             & cholesterol  \\
            \cmidrule[0.4pt]{1-2}
            Valid & 100  \\
            Missing & 0  \\
            Mean & 5.421  \\
            Std. Deviation & 0.524  \\
            Minimum & 4.364  \\
            Maximum & 6.550  \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
    }
\end{table}
```

Comment: It depends on which TeX installation you have.

Comment: If you installed TinyTeX as an R package, you should be able to install any TeX package with tinytex. I believe the command looks something like `tinytex::tlmgr_install('packagename')`. In your case it should be `tinytex::tlmgr_install('booktabs')`

Comment: Thank you. I have installed booktabs. But when using the knit command, the table does not show as html or pdf.
Below is the relevant portion of the output code:


`
bookdown::pdf_book:
  includes:
    in_header: preamble.tex
  latex_engine: xelatex
  citation_package: natbib
  bilbio-style: apa_like
  keep_tex: yes
bookdown::epub_book: default
`

Answer (score 1):

You must use `\usepackage{booktabs}` in the YAML header so it ended in the LaTeX breample, not in the body of the docuemtn, for instance, using the key `header-includes`, e.g.:

```
---
header-includes: \usepackage{booktabs}
output: pdf_document
---
Example:

\begin{tabular}{c}
\toprule a\\
\end{tabular}
```

Said that, this is the wrong way to make a table with descriptive statistics using Rmarkdown:

---

[image: mwe12]

---

[image: mwe3]

---

````
---
output: pdf_document
---

```{r,echo=F,results='asis', warning=FALSE}
x <- data.frame(cholesterol=rnorm(100,5.4,0.5)) # fake  data 
z <- data.frame(
Choresterol= c(sum(!is.na(x$cholesterol)),
sum(is.na(x$cholesterol)),
min(x$cholesterol),
max(x$cholesterol),
mean(x$cholesterol),
sd(x$cholesterol)))
rownames(z) <- c("Valid","Missing","Minimun","Maximum","Mean", "Std. Dev.")
options(xtable.comment = FALSE)
print(xtable::xtable(z,caption="Descriptive Statistics",align="lr"),
      booktabs=T,caption.placement="top")
```

```{r,echo=F,message=FALSE}
# simplest alternative
knitr::kable(summary(x), booktabs = T, caption="summary")
# more detalied alternative
knitr::kable(round(summarytools::descr(x),2), booktabs = T, caption="descr") 

```
````

Note that booktabs is used here without adding  anything in YAML header.